# Scenario to use the sg driver

Tags: linux, drivers, devices

Is there any device commonly controlled by SCSI generic driver (sg) in Linux today? I am curious about that.

Currently I just know the mtx tool which controls robots in tape libraries via sg driver.

Comment: If you like to get an answer, please better explain what kind of answer you are interested in.